# For what reasons might a patent issuance be delayed after the issue fee is paid?

Tags: time, fee, issue

I filed two applications last year in February. Both have been allowed, by different examiners. I received a notice of allowance on the first one **three weeks** after payment of the issue fee, and it issued shortly thereafter. It’s now been **more than six weeks** after the receipt of my issue fee on the second, but I have yet to receive a notice in the file wrapper. Is this unusual?

One wrinkle on the second application: my corrected ADS was rejected five months after I filed it, and weeks after I paid the issue fee. I’d filed it to enter the benefit info to the ADS that I had included in the first page of the specification, thus no new matter, but it was rejected as I had not included a petition. I called the help line and they told me there was nothing that could be done now, and I’d have to file a certificate of correction. So could the ADS issue somehow be the hold up on the issuance, or something else? Is it acceptable to contact the examiner about it?